# JSF select items from subclass

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to populate the list of an `<h:selectOneMenu>`.  However, the list that I am trying to retrieve is part of another class that is a variable in the base class.

Here is what I have and I'm not sure if this is even possible or how to do it.

I have a `Citation` class with the following:

```
public class Citation {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private Status status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then I have a `Status` class with the following:

```
public class Status {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public List<Status> getAll() {
        // goes to the database and gets a list of status objects
        System.out.println("I was called!");
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Then on my xhtml page, I have the following:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="citation_status" value="#{citation.status}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{citation.status.all}" var="s"
            itemLabel="#{s.name}" itemValue="#{s.id}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be calling the `getAll` method in the `Status` class at all.  When the page finishes loading, the select box is empty and the console does not have the output of `I was called!` from the `getAll()` method.

I'm a bit new to JSF and I've tried searching the best that I can, but I'm not really sure the terminology to use when searching for this because it's not technically called a "subclass", but that's the best name I can come up with, so needless to say, I've come up with nothing from searching.

**Additional Information**

If it helps:

- I'm using Glassfish as my application server
- I'm using Hibernate for my ORM
- I'm using JSF 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `#{citation.status}` returned `null`.

That said, this isn't going to work. The `h:selectOneMenu value` must match the same type as `f:selectItem itemValue` which is in this case an `int`. You would get a converter exception.

How to solve this the best depends on the functional requirement which is yet unclear in the question. Maybe you need `f:selectItem itemValue="#{s}"`, or you need `h:selectOneMenu value="#{citation.id}"`.

---

**Update**: as to the converter, here's a kickoff example:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Status.class)
public class URLConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        try {
            return someStatusDAO.findById(Long.valueOf(value));
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(String.format("Cannot convert %s to Status", value)), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((Status) value).getId());
    }

}
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, that would make sense because `status` has not been initialized.  For the `<f:selectItems>` value attribute, could I use `status.all` rather than `citation.status.all`?

Comment: If there's a `#{status}` somewhere in the scope, then certainly yes. You yet have to fix the potential conversion problem :)

Comment: That works for at least getting the items in the list.  As for the conversion problem, is there a way to set the value to an actual object?  I tried using `<f:selectItem itemValue=#{s}">`, but got the error `Error setting value Status for null Converter`.  I'm assuming that I need to look into using a Converter to handle this?

Comment: Right! :) Create a `@FacesConverter(forClass=Status.class)` which `implements javax.faces.converter.Converter`. Implement the two methods `getAsString()` (just let it return `id` as `String` or so) and `getAsObject()` (let it return "real" `Status` by obtained `id`) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a public getter for status in Citation.