# JSF Validation Error While Using Custom Converter

Tags: java, jsf

I am setting up a form using JSF (I'm pretty new at this) and I am getting a `Validation Error: Value is not valid` message on one of the fields.  This field is actually a separate object (as I will show below) that has a custom converter.

Here is what I have (with non-relevant code removed):

I have a `Citation` class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="citation")
public class Citation {
    private int id;
    private Status status;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I also have a `Status` class that you see referenced in the `Citation` class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="status")
public class Status {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters

    public List<Status> getAllStatuses() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.clear();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Status");
        List<Status> statuses = query.list();

        try {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

        return statuses;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Status)) return false;

        if (this.id == ((Status)obj).getId()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Then for my form, I have:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="citation_status" value="#{citation.status}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{status.allStatuses} var="s" itemValue="#{s.id}" itemLabel="#{s.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message for="citation_status" />
```

Lastly, for my converter, I have:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Status.class)
public class StatusConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // uses Hibernate to get the Status object (using a breakpoint in Eclipse, I have verified that this works)
        // I can post this code if needed, but just trying to keep it short :)
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((Status) value).getId());
    }
}
```

Now when I get to my form and submit, I get the `Validation Error` next to the Status.  I'm pretty new at this and thanks to @BalusC, I'm this far along.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Validation Error: Value is not valid

In case of `<h:selectOneMenu>`, you will get this when error whenever the selected item does not match any of the items available in the list. I.e. `selectedItem.equals(selectItem)` has never returned `true` for any of the items.

Since it's apparently a custom object (the `Status` class), did you implement its [`Object#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (and [`#hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)) properly? You can  if necessary let the IDE (Eclipse/Netbeans) autogenerate them.

#### See also:

- [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)
- [How to implement equals() in beans/entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/3181374#3181374)

---

**Update**: after having a closer look at your code, it turns out that you're actually submitting `#{s.id}` instead of `#{s}` (the whole `Status` object). Fix the `itemValue` accordingly and it should work (if `equals()` is still doing its job properly).

Comment: I'm assuming that I have implemented them correctly.  I have updated the code above to include them.  Maybe I am doing it incorrectly?

Comment: You only forgot `if (obj == this) return true` for the case there's no `id`. The `instanceof` also returns `false` for `null`, so the `obj == null` is superfluous. The `hashCode()` is a bit weak. But this shouldn't be the problem here. Can you ensure that the `getAllStatuses()` is been called during validations phase and that exactly the same list is been returned as during initial request (to display the form)?

Comment: I'm not really sure where I should put a breakpoint to check the validations phase?  I added the code that is used to get the list of `Status` objects above.  I assume that this code should return the same thing in both phases.

Comment: That did the trick.  Amazing what a difference a few characters can make :)  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: I peeked a bit in your question history and it turns out that I've already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711572/jsf-select-items-from-subclass/3711621#3711621) this in your previous question! ;)

Comment: Thank you! I was having the same problem (putting #{s.id} instead of #{s}), and I couldn't find a solution anywhere!